# LibreOffice Impress slide background image?

Tags: libreoffice

How do I set the first slide's background image to be different from the next slides background images in LibreOffice Impress?

NB: I am using LibreOffice 5, in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to create a second "background"- in german version it is called "Masterfolie"- the english version calls it "master". You can find it in Version 6 under "view" -"master".

After that You can set an master slide. Best would be to set the new slide for all slides, and just to set the special master slide for the first slide. After selecting the Slides in the slide pane on the left, You can find the master slider settings on the right side. See this picture: [Image](https://wiki.openoffice.org/w/images/thumb/9/9c/IG3-1-1.png/600px-IG3-1-1.png)

I know, this is from Openoffice, but it works on Libreoffice also